# How can operators be used with phrases in MySQL's boolean mode?

Tags: mysql, search, operators

I've been looking through the examples for boolean full-text searches in the MySQL [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/fulltext-boolean.html), and they don't quite give me enough information to work confidently with operators (specifically `+`, `-` and `*`) in conjunction with phrases (as opposed to individual words).  There are plenty of questions on StackOverflow about using boolean mode, but they're all very specific.

There's nothing in the MySQL Boolean Full-Text Searches documentation that says whether (and if so, how) operators can be used in conjunction with phrases.  For example, MySQL doesn't complain when I use the following query:

```
SELECT * AS relevance FROM deliverables WHERE MATCH(title,description) AGAINST('+"customer engagement" vendor' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
```

This suggests that the syntax is valid, yet it returns matches that **do not** include the word 'customer' anywhere in the title or description!  So the plus sign is clearly not having the expected effect.

**So my question could be rephrased: what are the rules for using operators with phrases?**

Sub-questions include things like:

- Is `+"some phrase"` valid?  *(My tests suggest so, but maybe the `+` is ignored.)*
- Is `-"some phrase"` valid?  *(My tests suggest so, and it seems to work as expected.)*
- Is `"som* phrase"` valid?  *(My tests suggest so, but it never matches anything.)*
- Is `"some phra*"` valid?  *(My tests suggest so, but it never matches anything.)*

Answer (score 0):

Use below syntax if want to match 3 words:

```
SELECT * FROM deliverables 
WHERE MATCH(title,description) 
AGAINST('+word1 +word2 +word3' IN BOOLEAN MODE);
```

Use below syntax if want to match 1 phrase:

```
AGAINST('"THIS IS MY"' IN BOOLEAN MODE);
```

Use below syntax if want results of either any one out of 2 phrase:

```
AGAINST('"THIS IS MY" "I AM NOT"' IN BOOLEAN MODE);
```

Please share if you want to get any specific results, if let me know the results what you want then I can help you in better way.

Comment: That doesn't help I'm afraid: all that query does is require all three words, whereas I want to (for example) require a specific phrase.  The question is about using operators with phrases, not with words.

Comment: Thanks for the extra comments.  It still doesn't answer my question, though, since I want to be able to **require** a particular phrase whilst optionally including other words or phrases.  Looking at the example in my original question, I want to require the phrase "customer engagement" and optionally include the word "vendor".  I believe this should be written `+"customer engagement" vendor`; however, as I said, this doesn't work as expected.

Comment: means u want all rows either contains "customer engagement" or "vendor". Is it correct.

Comment: `+"customer engagement" vendor` means "customer engagement" **must** be there and "vendor" would **ideally** be there.  `"customer engagement" vendor` means either "customer engagement" **or** "vendor" can be there.

Answer (score 0):

I was recently testing this out as well and came across your question.  Using MySQL 5.5 and testing your 4 conditions I see the following results:

### Is +"some phrase" valid?

The + sign is ignored, the same result set is returned if it is included or not.

```
SELECT a.*
FROM company a
WHERE a.active = 1 AND MATCH(a.company) AGAINST('+"social media"' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
```

### Is -"some phrase" valid?

The - sign is valid, but the search returns 0 results even when matching results are available.

```
SELECT a.*
FROM company a
WHERE a.active = 1 AND MATCH(a.company) AGAINST('-"social media"' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
```

### Is "som* phrase" valid?

The * is valid, but the search returns 0 results even when matching results are available.

```
SELECT a.*
FROM company a
WHERE a.active = 1 AND MATCH(a.company) AGAINST('"socia* media"' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
```

### Is "some phra*" valid?

The * is valid, but the search returns 0 results even when matching results are available.

```
SELECT a.*
FROM company a
WHERE a.active = 1 AND MATCH(a.company) AGAINST('"social medi*"' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
```

Comment: The `-"some phrase"` example (with no other terms) will always return no results because you must have matches to exclude results from.  (The MySQL documentation I linked above says: "Note: The - operator acts only to exclude rows that are otherwise matched by other search terms. Thus, a boolean-mode search that contains only terms preceded by - returns an empty result. It does not return “all rows except those containing any of the excluded terms.”")